# Sort list by a price, calculated by substrings from item inside list c#

Tags: c#, arrays, string, list, linq

I have a list that looks like this:

```
      Apple - 67 $ - 345 PIECES - 19:03
      Banana - 45 $ - 341 PIECES - 12:02
      Monkey - 34 $ - 634 PIECES - 16:01
```

And I want to order that list by the result of (money * amount) ordered, sort of "highest order ranking"

```
 finalResultOfTradeFiltering = finalResultOfTradeFiltering.OrderBy(x => Convert.ToDecimal(FindTextBetween(x,"-","$").Replace(" ", String.Empty)) * Convert.ToInt32(FindTextBetween(x, "-", "PIECES").Replace(" ", String.Empty))).ToList();
```

```
public string FindTextBetween(string text, string left, string right)
        {
            // TODO: Validate input arguments

            int beginIndex = text.IndexOf(left); // find occurence of left delimiter
            if (beginIndex == -1)
                return string.Empty; // or throw exception?

            beginIndex += left.Length;

            int endIndex = text.IndexOf(right, beginIndex); // find occurence of right delimiter
            if (endIndex == -1)
                return string.Empty; // or throw exception?

            return text.Substring(beginIndex, endIndex - beginIndex).Trim();
        }
```

However my code keeps crashing stating that the format is incorrect

Any clue anyone?

Comment: It's going to be based on the `FindTextBetween` code, but my guess is that `FindTextBetween(x, "-", "PIECES")` finds the text from the first `-` so you're trying to format `67$-345` instead of `345`.  Please include the `FindTextBetween` code so we can confirm if that is the problem.

Comment: You should write a class, can convert the string list into a list using the class type.

Comment: I am pretty sure i have tested FindTextBetween inside a foreach loop and it outputs the money amount correctly and the pieces amount, so nothing wrong with that

Comment: if possible try to use `Regex`  instead of finding index and pulling out substrings

Comment: Yes, the problem is as I suspected.  `FindTextBetween` is going from the first occurrence of `-`.  So you either need to update it to pass in an index it should start from, or tell it to skip the first occurrence.  Or better yet write a method to parse the entire string into a class with the values and then use that in your code.

Comment: Actually a quick fix would be to do `FindTextBetween(x, "$ -", "PIECES")` to make sure it's starting at that second `-` after the `$`

Comment: thanks juharr I tryed that with MessageBox.show(FindTextBetween(string, "$ - ", "PIECES") aand it outputs perfectly the pieces but when using it in the above method it just crashes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First do this:

```
public class Trade
{
    public string Product {get;set;}
    public decimal Price {get;set;}
    public int Quantity {get;set;}
    public string Time {get;set;} //Make this a DateTime or new TimeOnly later
    public string OriginalLine {get;set;}

    public static Trade Parse(string input)
    {
        var result = new Trade();
        result.OriginalLine = input;

        //example line
        //Apple - 67 $ - 345 PIECES - 19:03
        var exp = new RegEx(@" - (\d+) [$] - (\d+) PIECES - (\d{1,2}:\d{2})");
        var groups = exp.Match(input).Groups;

        result.Price = Convert.ToDecimal(groups[1].Value);
        result.Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(groups[2].Value);
        result.Time = groups[3].Value;

        int EndMarker = input.IndexOf(" - ");
        result.Product = input.SubString(0, EndMarker).Trim();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Then use the type like so:

```
var result = finalResultOfTradeFiltering.
    Select(t => Trade.Parse(t)).
    OrderByDescending(t => t.Price * t.Quantity).
    Select(t => t.OriginalLine);
```

Note the lack of a `ToList()` call. Sticking with IEnumerable as much as possible, rather than converting to a List again after each step, will save on RAM and sometimes CPU, making the code much faster and more efficient. Don't convert to a List until you really need to, which is likely much later than you would think.

Even better if you are able to convert the strings to objects much earlier in your process, and not return them back to strings until after all the other processing is finished.

Comment: thanks Joel also a great answer, also to get the calculated value(exmpl. , Apple - 67 $ - 345 PIECES - 19:03 - 23.115 $) may I do something like this ... => t.originalline + (t.Price * t.Quantity) ?

Comment: No, the original line is a string. **Always** be aware of the data type of your values. You only want the `t.Price * t.Quanity` part.

Answer (score 0):

You might use a pattern to get capture the digits and then do the calculation using Sort.

```
(\d+) \$ - (\d+) PIECES
```

- `(\d+) \$` Capture **group 1** for the money, match 1+ digits, a space and `$`
- `-` Match literally
- `(\d+) PIECES` Capture **group 2** for the amount, match 1+ digits and  `PIECES`

Assuming the pattern matches for all the given strings:

```
List<string> finalResultOfTradeFiltering = new List<string>() {
     "Apple - 67 $ - 345 PIECES - 19:03",
     "Banana - 45 $ - 341 PIECES - 12:02",
     "Monkey - 34 $ - 634 PIECES - 16:01"
};
var regex = @"(\d+) \$ - (\d+) PIECES";
finalResultOfTradeFiltering.Sort((a, b) => {
    var matchA = Regex.Match(a, regex);
    var matchB = Regex.Match(b, regex);
    var valueA = int.Parse(matchA.Groups[1].Value) * int.Parse(matchA.Groups[2].Value);
    var valueB = int.Parse(matchB.Groups[1].Value) * int.Parse(matchB.Groups[2].Value);
    return valueB.CompareTo(valueA);
});

finalResultOfTradeFiltering.ForEach(s => Console.WriteLine(s));
```

Output

```
Apple - 67 $ - 345 PIECES - 19:03
Monkey - 34 $ - 634 PIECES - 16:01
Banana - 45 $ - 341 PIECES - 12:02
```

Comment: thanks a lot,  how can I actually use this to further output the value of price * pieces ? soemthing like this : Apple - 67 $ - 345 PIECES - 19:03 - 23.115 $ ?

Comment: @HassanBrate You could format the items in the list again, and then format the number as you want. See https://ideone.com/FPd8j5